# Ubuntu 20.04 does not start after battery went dead

Tags: 20.04, battery

My battery went dead when using Ubuntu 20.04.
I use an old Dell Latitude 6400.
I charged it and then tried to start ubuntu but it did not start.
I can't even enter the BIOS.
It says "Press  to enter Configuration Utility ..." .
I pressed CTRL-I but nothing happened.

How can I fix this problem?

UPDATE:
I removed the laptop battery, put it back and got this message:
"Time-of-day not set - please run SETUP program
Strike the F1 key to continue, F2 to run the setup utility
Press F5 to run onboard diagnostics."

I coud enter the BIOS with F2.
Set year, month, day, hour, minute to the actual.
Exited the BIOS and got this message again: "Press  to enter Configuration Utility ..."
When I press CTRL-I nothing happens.

When I remove the laptop battery, put it back and got this message again:
"Time-of-day not set - please run SETUP program
Strike the F1 key to continue, F2 to run the setup utility
Press F5 to run onboard diagnostics."

Comment: The message you're seeing is for the system hardware, not Ubuntu itself. If you are using a Dell notebook, you will need to go into the UEFI/BIOS and confirm the date/time settings and other configuration aspects. If you are using an older computer, this could be a sign that the battery on the motherboard is in need of replacement.

Comment: Thanks. I use an old Dell Latitude 6400. Sorry, I did not mention but I cannot enter the bios. So I should replace the battery in the motherboard?

Comment: If you can *test* the motherboard battery first, that would confirm whether the little battery is in need of replacement. If you are unable to enter the UEFI/BIOS at all, even when the system is plugged in, there could be other issues at play.